# Name Resolution Failure, Windows Azure

Tags: wcf, azure

I am created a site on Windows Azure with a WCF service. When I reference it and trying to invoke it, I get this error:

UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00000] in :0 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0

My web service resolves to a host name and not an IP address. In Windows Azure, do I need to add a special setting to use the web service?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you trying to access a WCF service on Azure from your website, also on Azure. Or are you attempting to access the WCF service from somewhere else? If they're both on the Azure, are they in different roles? What's the URL that the application's attempting to use?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you provided, it seems you have a WCF web role running in Windows Azure and when you try to access it your get an error.

When you have WCF site hosted in Windows Azure you will have the service URL as below:
http://your_service_name.cloudapp.net/servicename/methodname

You would also need to have proper binding in your WCF service so it can be accessed from any client. This is the place most of the problems occur because wrong or bad bindings throw the service off so no one can connect. You can also verify that your WCF service returns the proper WSDL info when accessing it from a browser. It is a test to check the service reference URL. Have you verified that part?

When you will try to reference it in your client application, you will be using above reference URL which will list the function built into it and you can use it. With Windows Azure your service must resolved to a Hostname (not IP address which could change as it is VIP) so it is correct.

If you can get WSDL from the service but still can not get reference then you can still try using the service directly in your code by bindings the endpoint URL (on Azure) and then create the channel using binding and endpoint.